# A URL of a Hyperlinked Model Serializer returns '{"detail": "not found."} for a model with custom PK

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, serialization

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'user'
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
```

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['website', 'user', 'url']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'profile-detail', 'lookup_field': 'user'},
            'user': {'lookup_field': 'username', 'view_name': 'user-detail'}
        }
```

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('profile/', ProfileViewSet, basename='profile')

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

The code above **lists all profiles and their URL** in JSON format. However, when a URL is clicked, it returns '{"detail": "not found."} instead of showing the details of the profile. Any idea? Thanks!

- Django version: 3.0.4
- Django Rest Framework version: 3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

because the model defined in your serializer is `Profile` and your queryset uses different Model i.e `Retailer`.

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'user'
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made a mistake while typing the question. The queryset, as you mentioned, should be Profile. I have edited the question. Could you give it a second look?

Comment: @Yonas if you're still having the same problem also show the urls.py file.

Comment: it's been added.